# injecting Jersey client in Eclipse plugin

Tags: eclipse, dependency-injection, eclipse-plugin, jersey-client, jersey-2.0

I am developing an Eclipse Plugin. I am trying to bind a Jersey Client (jersey-client-2.3.1) to this plugin.

As far I read I need HK2 for dependency injection. It's fine when I run classes from the Eclipse or JUnit tests.

The problem comes when I want to run project as "Eclipse Application". New instance of Eclipse opens and then it cannot resolve/create an instance of Jersey client. Calling by ClientBuilder.newClient() gives an exception and trying to annotate with @Inject gives null. Looks like it doesn't have a context.

What should I do to make this working? Within Eclipse where I run unit tests everything works fine because there is only one (Jersey) lib provider so it binds it by default. How to make the same thing in new instance of Eclipse?

This is a list of libs that I am using:

```
asm-all-repackaged-2.2.0-b23.jar
bean-validator-2.2.0-b23.jar
cglib-2.2.0-b23.jar
class-model-2.2.0-b23.jar
config-types-2.2.0-b23.jar
core-2.2.0-b23.jar
hk2-2.2.0-b23.jar
hk2-api-2.2.0-b23.jar
hk2-config-2.2.0-b23.jar
hk2-locator-2.2.0-b23.jar
hk2-runlevel-2.2.0-b23.jar
hk2-utils-2.2.0-b23.jar
javax.annotation-api-1.2.jar
javax.inject-2.2.0-b23.jar
javax.ws.rs-api-2.0.jar
jersey-common-2.3.1.jar
osgi-resource-locator-1.0.1.jar
tiger-types-1.4.jar
jersey-client-2.3.1.jar
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

The problem was that when we want to add 3rd part libs for a plugin then we must add them to its classpath which is in plugin XML descriptor.

Thanks! :-)